# Error when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I'm on linux/manjaro.

I install matplotlib using pip with **sudo pip install matplotlib**.

When I do **pip list** matplotlib is there. However, when I try to import it with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I have this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

If I do `import matplotlib` I think it is working.

I have Python 3.6.4 and matplotlib 2.1.1.

SOLVED:
I named my file matplotlib.py, which is not good

Comment: Have you created a file yourself called `matplotlib.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you've made the classic mistake of importing a python script the same name as you are attempting to import.

If you've called your file `matplotlib.py` you will be importing your own script and you are not actually importing the module.  This also explains the `not a package` error because you are calling your own script.  If you have rename it to something else and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when trying to install. I had to use my package manager to download it from the repository.

From the official website:

> ### Linux : using your package manager
>
> > If you are on Linux, you might prefer to use your package manager. Matplotlib is packaged for almost every major Linux distribution.
> >
> > Debian / Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
> >
> > Fedora: sudo dnf install python3-matplotlib
> >
> > Red Hat: sudo yum install python3-matplotlib
> >
> > Arch: sudo pacman -S python-matplotlib

I'm not really sure what manjaro is based off of but hopefully that helped.